If a map between unital rings preserves multiplication and successor, does it preserve addition?
Welcome to my first MathOverflow posting!
This is a question about rings, all of them assumed to be both unital and associative.
Let $f\colon R\to S$ be a map between rings such that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$ and $f(1+x)=1+f(x)$ for any $x,y\in R$.
(This easily implies that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$.)
Is $f$ additive, that is, does $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in R$?
In my paper Is addition definable from multiplication and successor? (can also be downloaded from the HAL preprint server), I verified that the answer to that question is positive in many cases, including the following:

$R$ is finite;
$R$ is commutative (or even a ring of $2\times2$ matrices over a commutative ring);
$R$ is a full matrix ring, of order $>1$, over any ring;
$f$ is the power function $x\mapsto x^n$ over $R$;
$f$ is the determinant function on a ring of $3\times3$ matrices over a commutative ring...

and many other cases.
The answer to the question above is positive iff ring-theoretical addition has a positive existential (resp., positive primitive) definition from multiplication and successor.
I have been unable to settle this problem, in any direction. My (modest) computer attempts suggest that there should be a counterexample lurking somewhere, perhaps even in the existing ring theory literature.

The question https://mathoverflow.net/q/426302/88133 has comments and answers that seem relevant.

Have you tried the tropical ring?

I did check that link (not sure about how to mark it in my answer), however it seems to be mostly related to the integer ring, for which I know the answer to be positive.

About the tropical (semi) ring: in Section 11.1 of my paper I briefly discuss the example 0<a<b<1, with addition defined as maximum and multiplication zero unless of the factors is 1. Interchanging a and b yields a counterexample. However, there is no such example for finite cancellative semirings!

I'm a little confused by (4) and (5), which usually don't satisfy your hypotheses. Do you mean that, if they satisfy your hypotheses, then they satisfy the conclusion?

@FredWehrung Do you know an axiomatization of the variety generated by algebras of the form $(R,x\mapsto x+1,\cdot)$ for rings $R$? Or maybe for other intermediate reducts such as ones including the constants $0$ and $1$ or the negation function?

[LSpice] Yes, precisely!

@James No I don't have such an axiomatization! In my paper I call "brachynomials" the terms of that language --- that is, finite compositions of successor and multiplication. I don't know whether there are brachynomials $p$ and $q$ in three variables, representing distinct polynomials, such that $p(x,y,x+y)=q(x,y,x+y)$ everywhere.

You should attribute Julia Robinson's definition to Julia Robinson, not to Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey.

@EmilJeřábek Thanks, I had missed Robinson's reference!
